# WHAT RDBMS ( SQL SERVER/ ORACLE ) close to manage MYSQL(DBA)

Tags: mysql, rdbms

i have a requirement for learning MYSQL for DBA. here all training institutes teach on ORACLE AND SQL SERVER.
**SQL is mandatory to work on RDBMS. what RDBMS SYNTAX CLOSE TO MYSQL for DBA(backups, restore, performance tuning, etc  )**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer MySQL certification exam program and read MySQL documentation to know better about MySQL.

MySQL is much easy to setup and learn than SQL server and Oracle.

http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=458&get_params=p_track_id:MDBA